# Prevent Camera from going below Player in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I have a script where the player can control the camera with their mouse. The issue is that the player can use their mouse to move it below them, like this:

[image: Using mouse to bring camera below player]

I don't want this and want to stop the camera when it's Y Position is lower than the Player Y Position.

Here is my camera code:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 offset;

    public Transform player;

    public float camPosX;
    public float camPosY;
    public float camPosZ;

    public float camRotationX;
    public float camRotationY;
    public float camRotationZ;

    public float turnSpeed;

    private void Start()
    {
        offset = new Vector3(player.position.x + camPosX, player.position.y + camPosY, player.position.z + camPosZ);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(camRotationX, camRotationY, camRotationZ);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turnSpeed, Vector3.up) * Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * turnSpeed, Vector3.right) * offset;
            transform.position = player.position + offset;
        transform.LookAt(player.position);
    }
}
```

I have tried to fix this by checking if the Camera Y Position is less than the Player Y position and if that is true, I don't update the camera position.

Here is the code that I used for that:

```
    private void Update()
    {
        
        offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turnSpeed, Vector3.up) * Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * turnSpeed, Vector3.right) * offset;
        if (!((player.position + offset).y < player.position.y))
        {
            transform.position = player.position + offset;
        }
        transform.LookAt(player);
    }
```

This fixed the main issue, but made the whole camera movement thing sometimes glitchy... Like sometimes it completely stops moving and just looks at the player and not following it. Like this

[image: Camera movement glitching]

I am not sure how to fix this, any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a 3rd person camera as well, and I have solved this issue by shooting RayCast from the player to the camera. If the RayCast hit something, it placed the camera to the hit position.

In my script, I first **rotate** the camera and then I **"push"** it away from the player. The RayCast tells me how far I can push the camera.

> 1. You get user input and rotate the camera according to the input data. (At this point the camera is at the target position, eg.: player.)

> 2. You shoot a RayCast from the target position towards the camera. If it hits something and it is in a range you specified, then you set the camera position to the RayCast hitpoint.

I post my code here, so you can visualize what I'm talking about.

```
private Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.identity;  //Creates a quaternion with only zeros (x=0, y=0, z=0, w=0)
private float speedX;
private float speedY;

public void GetInput()
{
    speedX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    speedY = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
}

private void NormalRotation()
{
    //Set rotation values
    rotation.x += speedX * horizontalSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    rotation.y += speedY * verticalSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    rotation.y = Mathf.Clamp(rotation.y, -50, 90);

    //Apply rotation
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotation.y, rotation.x, rotation.z);
}
```

The variable `rotation` is a predefined `Quaternion` where I store my input values.
We only need to manage our X and Y coordinations as we only move on those axes.

I clamp Y, so the camera won't go below the player too much and won't go over it.

Then, I apply the rotation. (Keep in mind, that you might need to change the order of the axes according to your input handling. I probably changed up the two input, because my X and Y are switched.

And here is the distance calculation:

```
private void CalculateFinalPosition()
{
    //Setup temporary variables
    RaycastHit hit;
    Vector3 targetPosition = target.position + target.up * height;
    Vector3 direction = (transform.position - targetPosition).normalized;
    finalDistance = maxDistance;

    //Check collision
    if (Physics.Raycast(targetPosition, direction, out hit, Mathf.Infinity)) { finalDistance = hit.distance - 0.1f; }

    //Apply position
    finalDistance = Mathf.Clamp(finalDistance, minDistance, maxDistance);
    transform.position = (target.position + target.up * height) - transform.forward * finalDistance;
}
```

Now, this might require some explanation.

> `targetPosition` is equals to your target's position, however, I use some offset (height), so I calculate the final target position here.

> `maxDistance` represents a floating point number that you set. It limits how far the camera can get from the target.

> We shoot the RayCast into `direction` and see if it collides. If it does, we modify `finalDistance` to the distance of the hit (`hit.distance`). And I want to make sure, that the camera never collides with anything, so I push it a little towards the target (by 0.1).

> I clamp the `finalDistance` to keep it in the desired range. Then, I place the camera in the target position (`target.position + target.up * height`) and push it away (`-transform.forward * finalDistance`).

Here is a look of it's working process (You may want to manually set 0.1, because it might be a little buggy like here. You can experiment as much as you want with it to find the perfect value.):[image]

I give you a [link](https://github.com/B3N11/standalone-modules/tree/main/Around%20Camera) to the script if you would need it for reference or usage.

Comment: Thank you. I think @zoidberg's answer might be good  for my current testing map with no sides, but I do plan to make my map more complex and using Raycasts will help the camera not go into walls.

Comment: Also how do I create the `Quaternion` with the input values.. Sorry for a beginner question, second day of unity and c#...

Comment: It is pretty much nothing, you just create a variable. But I'll edit my answer, so it will be clear!

Comment: Okay, anyways I got it working, but i had to make some changes to your code.. If anyone from the future is reading this, here is the code that worked for me: https://pastebin.com/hrpwr3N3

Comment: Just a quick note! The Input Handling is in good place in the Update() method, but the NormalRotation() and CalculateFinalPosition() should be in LateUpdate(). This is just something that even Unity suggests to do. All camera movement should take place in LateUpdate() as it will be called at the end of the frame.

Comment: One more thing, I noticed that when the cube rotates, the camera starts glitching.. Like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-SPpLigPuo Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Interesting...normally the rotation shouldn't be a problem, I follow rotating objects with my camera and I haven't run into something like this...Let me try recreating the issue

Comment: I failed to recreate the issue. Shaking camera movement can occur in various scenarios. It might disappear after you apply the LateUpdate modification. If not, I don't think the problem is in the camera code, most likely in the scene setup or target control script. I can't say much blindly.

Comment: Can you send me your project? So i can see what exactly is going wrong..

Comment: I've put a link into the answer, but I'll put it here. This is my original camera controller script. Try using this. Read the README file pls, so you can use it correctly. The main part is to do this: In one of your scripts (where you want to get the input) call the SetValue(float x, float y) method. This way you can control the camera. https://github.com/B3N11/standalone-modules/tree/main/Around%20Camera

Comment: Let me look into this.

Comment: Your an absolute legend man. This fixed it. Tysm :DDDDD The reason my camera was glitching is because of my height i think i set it wrongly...

Comment: I'm very delighted :) Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you, have a great day :)

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is not updating the camera position instead of setting it to the player's height.

I think you could just compare the Camera Y value to the player's and if the camera's is less than the player's set them equal.

```
if(camPos.y < player.position.y)
{
    Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, player.position.y, transform.position.z);
    transform.position = newPosition;
}
```

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: I think it might work if the only thing you want is to prevent the camera from going below a certain level. I find this a good solution for that. However, as far as I’m concerned, this is syntax error. You are unable to modify transform.position values separately. You will need to create a Vector3 and then apply it to transform.position. But the idea seems correct to me.